# How to get Laravel 5.2 token in every AJAX Post Call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get laravel token in every AJAX Post request because I haven't using laravel form so no token automatically retrieved.

HTML BODY:

```
<input type="hidden" id="_token" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

My code:

```
function ajax_Call() {
    var formdata = $("form").serializeArray();
    token = $('#_token').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        token: token;
        data: formdata,
        success: function (r) {
        }
    });
}
```

But its not working.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add token to formData instead AJAX parameter:**

```
function ajax_Call() {
    var formdata = $("form").serializeArray();
    formdata.append("_token", $('#_token').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        success: function (r) {
        }
    });
}
```

**Will also Send token through headers:**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('#_token').val()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following header to your ajax

```
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('#_token').val();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ajaxPrefilter , to include token in your each ajax requst :

```
        $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, xhr) { // this will run before each request
    var t = $('input[name="_token"]').val(); // or _token, whichever you are using
   if (t) {
        return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', t); // adds directly to the XmlHttpRequest Object
    }
});
```

Now You have no need to add :

```
var t = $('#token').val();
```

in your each request . I hope this helps.